# Is it a bad practice to expose DB internal IDs in URLs?

Tags: java, database, url, web, obfuscation

Is it a bad practice to expose DB internal IDs in URLs?

For example, suppose I have a `users` table with some IDs (primary key) for each row. Would exposing the URL `myapp.com/accountInfo.html?userId=5`, where `5` is an actual primary key, be considered a "bad thing" and why?

Also assume that we properly defend against SQL injections.

I am mostly interested in answers related to the Java web technology stack (hence the java tag), but general answers will also be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Related question on softwareengineering.SE: [Should backend IDs be public or not on a REST API?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/346971)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That bases on the way you parse the URL. If you allow blind SQL injections that is bad. You have to only to validate the id from the user input.

Stackexchange also puts the id of the row into the URL as you can see in your address bar. The trick is to parse the part and get did of all possible SQL. The simples way is to check that the id is a number.

Comment: Yes. Let's assume that we properly defend against injections.

Comment: In this case that's is no problem maybe just some SEO stuff if you don't use "user friendly" urls.

Comment: Instagram exposes photo-ids too http://instagram.com/p/1. I guess it's safe to expose the ids if the site is read heavy and the data can't be modified and is not mission critical.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't a bad thing to pass through in the URL, as it doesn't mean much to the end user - its only bad if you rely on that value in the running of your application. For example, you don't want the user to notice that userId=5 and change it to userID=10 to display the account of another person.

It would be much safer to store this information in a session on the server. For example, when the user logs in, their userID value is stored in the session on the server, and you use this value whenever you query the database. If you do it this way, there usually wouldn't be any need to pass through the userID in the URL, however it wouldn't hurt because it isn't used by your DB-querying code.

Answer (score 3):

To use the database ID in URLs is good, because this ID should never change in an objects (db rows) life. Thus the URL is durable - the most important aspect of an URL. See also [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI).

Comment: Very, very wrong. As soon as you do this, your database becomes an obstacle to change.

Comment: If you have to change your database you could still use the old IDs even if they are no longer primary keys. All you have to do is what you would have done if you would have created artificial "web IDs" upfront.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a bad thing. You are exposing implementation detail. How bad? That depends. It forces you to do unneeded checks of the user input. If other applications start depending on it, you are no longer free to change the database scheme.

Comment: IMO primary keys can't change anyway once in production. And even if not in production you can't change them anyway since other tables might depend on them. Also in general I don't see any benefit that would be gained in changing primary keys. You have to expose *some* implementation detail since your URLs need some parameter in order to display a user (if you're using URL navigation at all that is).

Comment: @Simeon: of course primary keys change. Especially when redesigning the data model. I don't work in a waterfall context. The mapping to the database should not be exposed to any client. I might want to use a different storage layer.

Answer (score 1):

PKs are meant for the system.
 
To the user, it may represent a different meaning:
For e.g.
Let's consider following links. Using primary-key,it displays an item under products 
productA, productB,productC;

**(A)**http://blahblahsite.com/browse/productA/111 (pkey)
  **(B)**http://blahblahsite.com/browse/productB/112 (pkey)
  **(C)**http://blahblahsite.com/browse/productC/113 (pkey)
User on link **B** may feel there are 112 items under ProductB, which is misleading.

Also it will cause problem while merging tables since PK will be auto-incremented.

Comment: I don't think URLs are part of the user experience. No one types URLs anymore, I myself don't ever pay any attention to them, if I'm not developing something. So the fact that it is misleading doesn't seem very concerning to me. I do agree with the auto-increment argument however.

Comment: If you have a look at the stackexchange URLs they also contain several numbers which, if not DB related, are misleading.